Finding Local/Global Maxima of high-dimensional function in Mathematica
I am trying to find the local/global maxima of a function. This function is computed by taking the trace of a 64x64 matrix and summing over a bunch of indices. With my current implementation I have 90 parameters, each in [0,2π). I have conjectured that this function has an upper bound of 3, and it has a known lower bound of 0, as well as a known potential upper bound of 4, by definition.
Now the problem is that the expression of this function is too complicated for Mathematica to compute the functional term and it seems that built-in functions like NMaximize rely on having access to the function explicitly. While an explicit functional term for this function does exist, the full expression is too long to realistically compute or work with in any way. Numerically there is no issue to compute the function.
What I would like to do is just get a as-good-as-possible (within reason) estimator of local maxima and of course possibly global maxima, along with their point-coordinates, to get a better understanding of where these lie.
I tried using various functions such as NMaximize that are built into Mathematica, but none were able to return a value, independently of what optimization time I set.
I was hoping to get some returned value that further shows the upper bound I'm trying to prove.

Try to imagine for a few minutes that you don't know all the things you know about your problem. Imagine that ALL you know is the four paragraphs above, that the problem is apparently too big for Mathematica to handle, that the author appears to have some understanding of Mathematica and has tried all sorts of things and none of them work and the author wants the solution anyway. Really really try to imagine that. What can you possibly say to respond to his post? It doesn't appear you can try anything to see if it works because you don't have anywhere to start. What can you say or do for him?

Since you say numerically there is no issue to compute the function, try:
max=-Infinity; Do[{..90Names..}=RandomReal[{0,2Pi},90];val=..numericCalcWith90Names..;If[max<val,max=val;Print[max]],{10^7}] and see what it prints. If 10^7 takes too long then try 10^3. What I'd really like is 10 random values for every parameter, but you can't do 10^90.  You can enhance this by printing the param values with max and do this over and over, looking to see which params give larger max in a smaller range and mod the code to try a smaller range for those params. Please report What you get.

Do 10^n of those random trials for the biggest n that you can wait for. Then do 10^n more random trials using random range = the best values from that first run +/-10% or 5% or 25% for each param. And repeat. And repeat. And repeat. And start all over again with this. And repeat. And repeat.

I have previously tried such a Monte-Carlo approach, I havent checked how many evaluations I can fit into and hour or two. Using such an approach i got to ~2.2. I haven't yet tried to limit the parameterspace after getting a intermediary result. Will try that approach and write it here after my defense. However, I wondered if its possible to do e.g. a 'NMaximize' while not allowing symbolic computation of my custom function, and forcing it to repeatedly just call the function numerically.

In any case, gonna try that approach and see if something comes out.

If you are near or beyond the limits of MMA with the computer you have then it may be difficult to coax MMA into understanding how you want it to do something. The details of the implementation of internal algorithms used by any function are usually not not documented so don't know how to avoid symbolic. You might try Method->"RandomSearch" along with trying to adapt StepMonitor to capture the progress NMaximize is making before you finally give up and kill it. Printing the progress at each step seems to usually slow it down and that is probably what you don't want to have happen.

So I have been able to reduce the number of parameters from 90 to 9 real-valued and 12 complex-valued parameters, with 3 requirements that these have to fulfill. This has allowed me to run an NMaximize and it has returned the expected value of 3, which is great. The main problem is that I cannot rule out the possibility that this is a local Maximum, but what I have is already plenty. Is there a way for NMaximize to run with starting parameters or with some random seed to check for different optimizations and if they reach a different maximum? I couldn't find anything on the page.

If you haven't already done so, clicking on the Details and Options on the help page for NMaximize will describe when it is guaranteed to return a global maximum, but readers cannot know if your function is "linear or concave and cons are linear or convex" or not. Further down in that page you can read about Method-> and see if any of those apply. You can try Method->"RandomSearch" and see what that gives you, but that clearly states that may not return a global maximum. But I don't believe that just throws random points at your function and don't know if that is exactly what you want.
